# Rewrite query without use of lateral joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a simpler way to express the query below, without the use of lateral joins (not supported by my ORM) ?

```
select 
    v.id,
    v.name,
    v.avatar,
    sent_at,
    opened_at,
    replied_at
from visitors v
left join auto_message_events ame on ame.visitor_id = v.id
left join lateral (
    select inserted_at as sent_at from auto_message_events ame
    where ame.visitor_id = v.id and ame.event = 'sent'
) as sent on true
left join lateral (
    select inserted_at as opened_at from auto_message_events ame
    where ame.visitor_id = v.id and ame.event = 'opened'
) as opened on true
left join lateral (
    select inserted_at as replied_at from auto_message_events ame
    where ame.visitor_id = v.id and ame.event = 'replied'
) as replied on true
where ame.auto_message_id = 99
limit 10
```

Comment: As always, some context would be helpful. Table definitions, Postgres version, cardinalities. Most importantly: is the combination `(visitor_id, event)` *unique* in `auto_message_events`?

Comment: `where ame.auto_message_id = 99`  I rest my case.

Answer (score 0):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select v.id, v.name, v.avatar,
       max(case when  ame.event = 'sent' then ame.inserted_at end) as sent_at,
       max(case when  ame.event = 'opened' then ame.inserted_at end) as opened_at,
       max(case when  ame.event = 'replied' then ame.inserted_at end) as replied_at
from visitors v join
     auto_message_events ame 
     on ame.visitor_id = v.id
where ame.auto_message_id = 99
group by v.id
limit 10;
```

I'm not sure if the `where` clause is actually needed, because its purpose may be to only return one row per visitor in the original table.

Comment: Hi Gordon - Your link doesnt work. blog.data-miners.com. Can you share me the working one... I like the answers you post on stackoverflow and would like to know if you have any good learning material for solving complex sql questions. thank you.

Comment: @SOaddict . . . I would point you to my book "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel".

Comment: Can u help me answering this ques... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801594/how-to-get-new-and-returned-ytd-mtd-wtd-users-in-a-user-traffic-table